# FormType and FormHandler as services in Symfony3

Tags: forms, service, symfony

So I'm trying to use a FormType with a FormHandler through their respective services to get a pretty clean Form flow.
Now the problem is that I get an error in Symfony 3.0:
`Expected argument of type "string", "AppBundle\Form\Type\CurrencyType" given`

I'm not really sure how to work with this in the new version.

The FormType:

```
/**
 * Class CurrencyType
 * @package AppBundle\Form\Type
 */
class CurrencyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('displayName', TextType::class)
            ->add('symbol', TextType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Voeg Currency toe'))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Currency'
        ));
    }
}
```

The Form Handler:

```
class CurrencyFormHandler
{
    /**
     * @var Request
     */
    protected $requestStack;

    /**
     * @var CurrencyManager
     */
    protected $currencyManager;

    /**
     * @var FormInterface
     */
    protected $form;

    /**
     * CurrencyFormHandler constructor.
     * @param FormInterface $form
     * @param RequestStack $requestStack
     * @param CurrencyManager $currencyManager
     */
    public function __construct(FormInterface $form, RequestStack $requestStack, CurrencyManager $currencyManager)
    {
        $this->form = $form;
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->currencyManager = $currencyManager;
    }

    /**
     * Process the form
     *
     * @param Currency|null $currency
     * @return bool
     */
    public function process(Currency $currency = null)
    {
        if (null === $currency) {
            $holiday = $this->currencyManager->create();
        }
        $this->form->setData($currency);
        $this->form->handleRequest($this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest());
        if ($this->form->isValid()) {
            $this->onSuccess($currency);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * When the form is succesfully posted
     *
     * @param Currency $currency
     */
    public function onSuccess(Currency $currency)
    {
        $this->currencyManager->save($currency);
    }
}
```

The services:

```
<service id="app.currency.form" class="Symfony\Component\Form\Form">
            <argument>app_currency</argument>
            <argument type="service" id="app.currency.form.type" />
            <factory method="createNamed" service="form.factory" />
        </service>
        <service id="app.currency.form.type" class="AppBundle\Form\Type\CurrencyType">
            <tag name="form.type" alias="currencyform"/>
        </service>
        <service id="app.currency.form.handler"
                 class="AppBundle\Form\Handler\CurrencyFormHandler">
            <argument type="service" id="app.currency.form" />
            <argument type="service" id="request_stack" />
            <argument type="service" id="app.currency.manager"/>
        </service>
```

And the controller:

```
/**
 * Class AddController
 * @package AppBundle\Controller\Currency
 */
class AddController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/currency/add", name="currency_add")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->get('app.currency.form');
        $formHandler = $this->get('app.currency.form.handler');
        $process = $formHandler->process();

        if ($process) {
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Currency succesvol toegevoegd');
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('currency_overview'));
        }

        return $this->render(':currency:add.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

So what exactly is wrong here? This used to work all the time in Symfony 2

Comment: This <argument type="service" id="app.currency.form.type" /> is passing an instance of your form type.  S3 can only use a class name, hence the error.  Change your service definition to inject a string instead of a service.  It's a bit strange but the form factory will then use your form type service based on the fully qualified class name.  This is one of several major form bc breaks which you will encounter.  Best to reread the manual on forms and pretty much start over for S3.

Answer (score 0):

Your Form handler doesn't look right.
You've declared:

```
/**
 * @var CurrencyManager
 */
protected $currencyManager;
```

But this I believe by default is a string.
Then you do this:

```
public function onSuccess(Currency $currency)
{
  $this->currencyManager->save($currency);
}
```

Trying to set it to a "Currency" instead of a "string"!